# Curved rectangle shape android

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to create a rectangle shape in XML, it needs a curved shape.
Is this possible with the XML markup or programmatically?

the code i have now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="45dp"
        android:topRightRadius="45dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="45dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="45dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#4F4F4F" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#878787" />
</shape>
```

Can someone help me out?

[image]

My idea is as followed:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD7I0.png]

The rectangle has to be transformed with a curve.

Comment: that looks like an arc

Comment: did you check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a shape resource for your view background, either an oval:

```
<shape android:shape="oval">
 <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF000000" />
</shape>
```

or a rectangle with rounded corners:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
 <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF000000" />
 <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

it's not clear to me from your question what you're looking to do exactly.  The oval will fit to your objects width and height.

Of course you can have precise control via a custom Drawable, implementing your own draw() method and painting on the canvas.  This is likely your best approach if you're looking for something very specific.

Comment: due your question, I've made an example of what I have mentioned --> http://i.stack.imgur.com/RD7I0.png